# How do I make "<f:form.select>" a mandatory field (required)?

Tags: php, typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

Users are required to pick an option from this select:

```
<f:form.select name="role" options="{role}" optionLabelField="title" optionValueField="uid" size="4" />
```

The fluid select element has no required or minItems-Attribute. I don't want to check for missing arguments in the controller because the form is quite complex and I don't want to make users enter all the data again after $this->redirect("show").

I would prefer to have exactly the same implementation as with :

```
<f:form.textfield name="foo" required="true" />
```

which works like a charm. How would I do this?

Comment: You can use additional attribute for this, check out this.. [Link](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/7.5.0/Form/SelectViewHelper.html). Hope this will help you!

Comment: When I add  additionalAttributes="{required: 'required'}" to the select nothing changes in the frontend (I don't get this attribute). I'm using Fluid 8.7.8, maybe they removed additionalAttributes for some reason. But thanks anyway …

Comment: This must be `additionalAttributes="{required:'required'}"`

Comment: Hi Ghanshyam, that did the trick. Thanks again!

Comment: Have fun! KeepCoding :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Ghanshyam pointed out you have to add
`additionalAttributes="{required:'required'}"`
to the `<f:form.select>` element. It does **not** work with whitespace within the attribute value.